# Validación de uniqueness no funciona Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Estoy tratando de probar que un **foreign key** sea único, ya que solo puede existir una relación en esa tabla por usuario.

Mi duda es que no se si tengo que poner una restricción en la tabla indicando que el campo foráneo también sea único, o solo colocando la validación **uniqueness** en el ActiveRecord funciona.

Mi `ActiveRecord`:

```
class Balance < ActiveRecord::Base
  #association macros
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wallet

  #validation macros
  validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :wallet_id, presence: true
end
```

Mi `Factory`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :balance do
    user
    wallet
    amount 2000
  end
end
```

Mi test:

```
RSpec.describe Balance, type: :model do

  let(:balance) { FactoryGirl.create :balance }

  it "when is valid" do
    expect(balance).to be_valid
  end

  it "when is presence user_id" do
    expect(balance).to validate_presence_of :user_id
  end

  it "when is presence wallet_id" do
    expect(balance).to validate_presence_of :wallet_id
  end

  it "when is uniqueness user_id" do
    expect(balance).to validate_uniqueness_of :user_id #falla
  end


  it "when is belongs_to :user" do
    should belong_to(:user)
  end

  it "when is belongs_to :wallet" do
    should belong_to(:wallet)
  end

end
```

Error

```
Balance when is uniqueness user_id
     Failure/Error: let(:balance) { FactoryGirl.create :balance }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User has already been taken
     # ./spec/models/balance_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/balance_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Comment: Me parece que debe haber algún error en tu prueba cuando creas el Factory porque la prueba está arrojando el resultado correcto del comportamiento esperado de uniqueness; te dice que el user_id debe ser único y ya fue creado en otro registro.
Investiga sobre before(:each) tal vez allí este tu solución

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Mi duda es que no se si tengo que poner una restricción en la tabla indicando que el campo foráneo también sea único, o solo colocando la validación uniqueness en el ActiveRecord funciona.

No es necesario (aunque si recomendado) poner restricciones en la base de datos.

El error está en el test que falla al intentar crear una instancia extra de `Balance` (y se encuentra con que vos ya creaste una antes).

### Notas

Estaría bueno que recortes un poco los bloques de código, de manera que las preguntas sean más concisas.

En estos casos es importante comentar sobre las librerías que estás usando, en este caso el error está en el uso de [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb) que no es mencionada en la pregunta.

Testear este tipo de detalles suele no ser necesario e inclusive ser contraproducente, Rails tiene sus propios tests, no es necesario volver a testearlo.

Por último, si insisten en testear eso, es conveniente persistir las instancias en la base de datos (`FactoryGirl.create`) mientras alcanza con utilizar `FactoryGirl.build` que es mucho más rápido.

### Actualización

Shoulda no funciona bien cuando la validación de unicidad es sobre una `foreing_key`, porque [intenta asignarle 'a' como valor](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb#L372).

Si todavía querés hacer el test, se puede hacer a mano:

```
it 'validates uniqueness on user_id' do
  balance # creo la instancia del let
  dup_balance = balance.dup
  dup_balance.user = balance.user
  expect(dup_balance).not_to be_valid
end
```

Igualmente, hacer este tipo de tests es poco recomendable.

Comment: Pero en que momento creo la instancia anterior de balance?, lo que entiendo de mi test es que creo una instancia balance con la instrucción `let(:balance) { FactoryGirl.create(:balance) }` y luego esa instancia la comparo en los diferentes `it`.

Comment: La instancia la creas ahí, pero `validate_uniqueness_of` no compara, lo que hace es crear otra instancia y checkear que la validación funciona. El problema es que la instancia que le pasas está guardada en la base de datos (shoulda espera que sea una instancia sin guardar) y que shoulda no esta preparado para que el uniqueness se use sobre una columna de enteros (intenta asignarle 'a' y falla). [veasé el código acá][https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb#L372]

Comment: Ya di con mi error, el problema era como lo mencionabas, había un registro en base de datos que violaba la unicidad para ese usuario pero el registro se creaba en un callback que estaba en el modelo `User` tenia esto `after_create :create_balance_account` esto creaba un registro para los usuarios que se creaban, y cuando hacia el `FactoryGirl.create(:balance)` ya creaba un usuario con balance y se disparaba el error, pero gracias por la guía y tu tiempo.